# Detecting Halo in Images

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I've never done any image processing and I was wondering if someone can nudge me in the right direction.

Here's my issue: I have a bunch of images of black and white images of places around a city. Due to some problems with the camera system, some images contain nothing but a black image with a white vignette around the edge. This vignette is noisy and non-uniform (sometimes it can be on both sides, other times only one).

What are some good ways I can go about detecting these frames? I would just need to be able to  write a bit.

My image set is huge, so I would need this to be an automated process and in the end it should use Python since it needs to integrate into my existing code.

I was thinking some sort of machine learning algorithm but I'm not sure what to do beyond that.

Comment: Machine learning seems like overkill for this problem. If you use an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection algorithm you'll find that there are no edges in most of the "junk" images which should be enough based on your description. SciPy filters http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.filters should provide the tools you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In photographic circles the "halos" are referred to as vignetting. A google search for "Vignetting Removal Algorithms" yields tons of useful results like

[Vignette and Exposure Calibration and Compensation](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/vignette/vign.iccv05.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then you have *complete* black images with white borders?

In this case I think the easiest approach is to compute a histogram of the intensity values of the pixels, i.e. how „dark/bright” is the overall image. I guess that the junk images are significantly darker than the non-junk images. You can then filter the images based on their histogram. For that you have to choose a threshold: Every image darker than this threshold is considered as junk.

If this approach is to fuzzy you can easily improve it. For example: just compute the histogram of the inner image without the edges, because this makes the histogram much more darker in comparison to non-junk images.

Comment: DO you think finding all the frames with the halo effect in it, averaging them, and then taking the correlation of that "halo template" and an image with unknown effect would work? I'd have to empirically figure out at what threshold to cut off at...